# Ampere's Law and net current?

Tags: electromagnetism

[image]

If the current through a closed Amperian curve is zero, the net circulation around the closed curve should be zero.

In the image, above the entire field is perpendicular to the Amperian curve when it enters the curve, but is not entirely perpendicular to the closed Amperian curve when it leaves. Therefore the dot product will be greater when the lines enter than when they leave, so the net circulation wouldn't be zero would it?

However, the net current is zero, so the net circulation should be zero right? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Be aware one doesn't calculate flux when dealing with Amperian loops. Flux is for vector fields dotted into normal surface vectors, which you aren't doing here.

Comment: That is a good point @BMS. The term to use here is cirulation. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contributions from the left and right sides are not the same because they have different lengths. This discrepancy will cancel out the contribution from the lower edge.

This can be seen since the contribution from the left edge and the bottom will just be the current times the vertical distance traveled. Clearly the contribution from the left side and bottom will be the same as the contribution from the right side, since they traverse the same vertical distance. Since they are going in opposite directions, their contributions cancel and there line integral is zero, as it should be since there is no curl (in other words, no current) in the enclosed region.

Comment: What do you mean by left and right sides?

Comment: Do you want me to explain what left and right mean or what a side is?

Comment: Both please. I mean I know what a side, left and right mean, I just don't understand what they mean in this context.

Comment: Ok I will try. You have a picture in your question. In this picture is shown a loop which has the shape of a [trapezoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid). The trapezoid has four sides. I think you should be with me so far. I call the four sides the top side, the bottom side, the left side, and the right side. The top side is the one the top, the left side is the one on the left, etc. Does that clear everything up?

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, why would there be any contribution from the left and right side? They're parallel to the field

Comment: because you are calculating $\int \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{l}$ So if they are parallel, the dot product is non-zero so you get a contribution.